# Removing specific words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, stop-words

Sample table:

| a |
| --- |
| ryzen cpu,ryzen 5 5600x,best,amd ryzen,sale |
| cpu,ryzen 9 7800x,available,computer for ryzen,new |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['ryzen cpu,ryzen 5 5600x,best,amd ryzen,sale',
                         'cpu,ryzen 9 7800x,available,computer for ryzen,new']})
```

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, wordnet
stop = stopwords.words('english')
b = ['best', 'sale', 'new','available']
c = stop + b
x = []
for i in df['a'].str.split(','):
    for j in i:
        if j not in b:
            x.append(j)
print(x)
```

I am trying to remove the stopwords and other specific words as mentioned above, even though the other words are getting removed, but stopwords are not.

This is the output I am getting:

```
['ryzen cpu', 'ryzen 5 5600x', 'amd ryzen', 'cpu', 'ryzen 9 7800x', 'computer for ryzen']
```

Also I am not able to get it in table format, I have tried to use the following list comprehension but it is not working:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([j for i in x.split(' , ') for j in i if j not in c]))
df['a']
```

the output it is giving seems completely off (some of the letters are completely gone, such as "ryzen" has become "rzen" and "sale" has become "le" etc):

| a |
| --- |
| rzen cpu,rzen 5 5600x,be, rzen,le |
| cpu,rzen 9 7800x,vlble,cpuer fr rzen,new |

If anyone can please help me understand what exactly I am doing wrong, and how to proceed further with this ?

the expected output looks something like this:

| a |
| --- |
| ryzen cpu,ryzen 5 5600x,amd ryzen |
| cpu,ryzen 9 7800x,computer ryzen |

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the stop words really, only your additional words, look at this line

```
if j not in b:
```

Change b to c here.

It really, really helps debugging if you name your variables so that the names mean what they contain.

As for the loops here, the code looks very hard to read, let's understand it step by step

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([j for i in x.split(' , ') for j in i if j not in c]))
```

- `i` - is word in `x` (in part `for i in x.split(' , ')`)
- `j` - is a symbol in `i` (`for j in i`)
- then some filtering of `j` is performed (`if j not in c`)
- then `j` are joined together

That's how you get random symbols in the end. I think a right thing to do is to get rid of lambda in apply, because there's too much logic in it - it's easy to get confused. It may be better to write a separate function and apply it.

(by the way don't split by `" , "`, split by `","`!)

```
def filter_stop_words(values, stop_words=c):
    words = values.split(",")
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in stop_words, words))

df['a'].apply(filter_stop_words)
```

Comment: Hi Maria, thank you for answering, I was able to remove the specific words, but the stop words: "for" is not getting removed, do I have to tokenize the words before applying the stopwords removal ?  Also I have another query, so i was able to remove the stopwords and do the other lexical analysis steps with the keywords when they are in multiple rows, like: ['ryzen','ryzen 9, 'computer for gamers', 'available'] but on merging the rows and dropping the duplicate rows, I am left with additional commas for eg: ['ryzen,ryzen 9,,ryzen5800x'] etc. There are 2 commas, I just want to have 1 comma

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('|'.join(c), "", regex = True).replace(',,', ',', regex = True)
```

The last replace is to remove `,,` where the double comma marks a removed item

Comment: I followed this, but the output looks similar to the output I got earlier: [rzen cpu,rzen 5 5600x, rzen,]

Comment: Using your data and the code above I get `ryzen cpu,ryzen 5 5600x,amd ryzen,` which is what you require (apart from the trailing comma which can easily be removed). Something else seems to be going on beyond the info you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

STOPS = set(stopwords.words('english') + ['best', 'sale', 'new','available'])
def remove_stops(words):
    if (words := [word for word in words if word not in STOPS]):
        return words

df['a'] = (df['a'].str.split(',').explode().str.split()
           .map(remove_stops).dropna()
           .str.join(' ').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

Result for your sample dataframe:

```
                                   a
0  ryzen cpu,ryzen 5 5600x,amd ryzen
1   cpu,ryzen 9 7800x,computer ryzen
```